# Getting a town from coordinates android

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get a town from coordinates that I get from the phone's GPS. here is what I am working with:

```
public void locationStart(View v){
    gps = new GPSTracker(GetHelpNow.this);

    if(gps.canGetLocation()){
        double lat = gps.getLatitude();
        double lng = gps.getLongitude();

        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
        List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
        if(addresses.size() > 0) {
            String town = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Town: " + town, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(
                    getApplicationContext(),
                    "Your Location is -\nLat: " + lat + "\nLng:"
                            + lng, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }else{
        gps.showSettingsAlert();

    }
}
```

I know the code that gets the coords works, my issue is at the line:

```
List<Address> addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

I get an Unhandled Exception: java.io.IOException error.
I am new to this, and I am sure it is simple, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to use try and catch around it like below:

```
try {
        addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```